# ASP.NET Chart Column Widths

Tags: asp.net, charts

I have the following ASP.NET dynamic chart below.  How do I puta lines going down the chart for each date on the x axis.  There are currently 3 lines going down the y axis, Jul 2009, May 2010, and Mar 2011.  I want a line for each date, so you can see each point on the line and I also want to display each date that a point is placed on the chart.

Also, there seems to padding at the start and end of the chart and no right border.  How do I get rid of the padding and get the right border in place?

[chart image](http://s10.postimage.org/95nk8sgyh/Chartingchart_Img.jpg)

Here is my code:

Front End:

```
<asp:Chart ID="chtReport" runat="server" Width="650px" Height="400px" ImageType="Jpeg">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="TotalLine" YValueType="Double" ChartType="Line" ChartArea="MainChartArea" />
        <asp:Series Name="GoalLine" YValueType="Double" ChartType="Line" ChartArea="MainChartArea" />
        <asp:Series Name="AverageLine" YValueType="Double" ChartType="Line" ChartArea="MainChartArea" />
       <asp:Series Name="TotalPoint" YValueType="Double" ChartType="Point" ChartArea="MainChartArea" />
       <asp:Series Name="GoalPoint" YValueType="Double" ChartType="Point" ChartArea="MainChartArea" />
       <asp:Series Name="AveragePoint" YValueType="Double" ChartType="Point" ChartArea="MainChartArea" />
   </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="MainChartArea">
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

Back End

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (DateTime date = startDate; date <= ChartDetails.EndDate; date = date.AddMonths(1))
    {
        dates.Add(date.ToString());
    }

    grdChart.DataSource = dates;
    grdChart.DataBind();

    chtReport.ChartAreas["MainChartArea"].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
    chtReport.ChartAreas["MainChartArea"].AxisY.Maximum = 100;
    chtReport.ChartAreas["MainChartArea"].AxisX.Title = "Date Range";
    chtReport.ChartAreas["MainChartArea"].AxisY.Title = "Percent";
}


protected void grdChart_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    // Extra Code above...

    chtReport.Series["TotalLine"].Points.AddXY(rowDate.ToString("MMM yyyy"), total);
    chtReport.Series["GoalLine"].Points.AddXY(rowDate.ToString("MMM yyyy"), total);
    chtReport.Series["AverageLine"].Points.AddXY(rowDate.ToString("MMM yyyy"), total);

    chtReport.Series["TotalPoint"].Points.AddY(total);
    chtReport.Series["GoalPoint"].Points.AddXY(rowDate.ToString("MMM yyyy"), total);
    chtReport.Series["AveragePoint"].Points.AddXY(rowDate.ToString("MMM yyyy"), total);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following line of code and I now have the grid lines I was looking for.

```
chtReport.ChartAreas["MainChartArea"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `style="padding:0"` or use external style sheet (CSS) to set padding 0

Comment: I added a style with 0 padding with no luck. Besides the padding issue, I still want to show a line on for going up the Y Axis for each date on the chart.